# Sort TypeScript files by dependencies in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sorting, dependencies, typescript

I have some files and some of them have dependencies some of them dont.
There are also cicle dependencies. I want to sort this files by this dependencies to concat the files later in the correct order.

This are TypeScript files, but I collect all files in a NodeJS program where I want to sort the TypeScript files.

Example  (This are only random names):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for some answers of things that I already knew, I found a correct answer by myself, here is my solution:

```
var stack = [];
var visited = [];

function topologicalSortUtil(item) {
    visited.push(item.fullPath);
    for (var i = 0; i <= item.dependencies.length - 1; i++) {
        var dependency = item.dependencies[i];
        if (visited.indexOf(dependency.fullPath) !== -1) {
            continue;
        }
        topologicalSortUtil(dependency);
    }
    stack.push(item);
}

function topologicalSort(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        if (visited.indexOf(item.fullPath) !== -1) {
            continue;
        }
        topologicalSortUtil(item);
    }
    return stack;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q5vbj2kv/)**

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddTC4Zovtbc

https://github.com/mission-peace/interview/blob/master/src/com/interview/graph/TopologicalSort.java

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here, the first is basically "you don't need to" and the other is use a tool to put Humpty Dumpty together.

1. Node will handle `require` for you if you use commonjs as your module arg when compiling your TypeScript, then when running Node will load the dependencies for you at runtime
2. You can concat/bundle your output with with tools like [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/)/[browserify](http://browserify.org/) which will analyze your dependencies and put the files/contents in the right order in a single output file

Comment: I know that I dont have to do this, but it has a reason why i want todo it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can place reference tags at the top of each file, and use the `--out` CLI option. TSC will figure out the rest. Circular dependencies won't break TSC, but you do need to take into account that something may not exist yet at runtime.

Shape.ts

```
/// <reference path="Test.ts"/>
```

Test.ts

```
/// <reference path="Vector.ts"/>
```

Vector.ts

```
/// <reference path="Group.ts"/>
/// <reference path="Shape.ts"/>
```

Comment: Really recommend not using out: http://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Comment: @andrej What's really not being recommend there is the use of internal modules. I don't recommend using them either, but J. Schilling already explained that s/he still wants to.